# Find all instances where a character string contains one value and does not contain another value in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, subset

I am trying to find instances in a vector where there are values which are conflicting.

Here is an example of my data:

```
x <- rep(c("SP", "MC: SP", "3xSP", "MC", "BF"), 10)
z<- rep(c("SP", "MC", "BF", "OFF SP", "SP"), 10)
d <- rep(c("SP", "OFF SP", "MC", "OFF SP", "SP"), 10)
y <- rep(c("OFF SP", "SP", "MC", "BF", "DC"), 10)
specials <- paste(x, y, z, d, sep = " ")
comp <- abs(rnorm(50))
data <- data.frame(specials, comp)
```

What I want to do, is create a new data frame (say, "conflict") which contains the "comp" numbers for all instances where specials contains both "OFF SP" and any version of "SP" ("3xSP", "2 SP : MC" etc)

I have used the function `grep()` to subset the data into instances where specials contains "SP" OR "OFF SP"

```
SPsub <- data[grep("SP", data$specials), ]
OFFSPsub <- data[grep("OFF SP", data$specials), ]
```

But I want a new dataframe, which is a subset of data, which only contains the information for when specials contains both some version of "SP" AND "OFF SP"

Is there any way to do this?

I've tried this, but it does not work; and returns an empty data frame

```
  OnlySP <- SPsub[!grep("OFF", SPsub$comp), ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Just specify both in the regex, adding `.*` to allow space: `data[grepl('SP.*OFF SP', data$specials), ]`

Comment: Every row of `data` has `SP`.  Can you narrow down your pattern?

Comment: Also, your final line is trying to do regex on a numeric variable.

Comment: Thanks Alistaire. I tried this on my real-life data, but it is still returning some instances where "SP" and "OFF SP" are not both present. In the real data, 'specials' is a concatenation of earlier columns. So the value for specials could sometimes be "OFF SP: OFF SP: BC: MF: OFF SP". The code you provided also returns these instances. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your last code example, are you in fact just looking for "OFF" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `grepl()`:

```
> data[grepl("SP OFF.*SP|SP.*SP OFF", data$specials), ]
    specials       comp
1  SP OFF SP 0.73167778
6  SP OFF SP 0.57968263
11 SP OFF SP 0.26899478
16 SP OFF SP 0.09352101
21 SP OFF SP 0.82593920
26 SP OFF SP 1.63878597
31 SP OFF SP 0.07576427
36 SP OFF SP 0.14606374
41 SP OFF SP 0.20326698
46 SP OFF SP 0.92467844
```

I used the following regex pattern:

```
SP OFF.*SP|SP.*SP OFF
```

This matches `SP OFF` either followed by, or preceded by, by a second occurrence of `SP`.

Comment: You need to provide with a reproducible sample data.  My updated answer meets the requirements, as far as you have shown us.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The problem is that in my real life data 'specials' is a concatenation of earlier columns, which should not contain both values, but sometimes do in error. The values for 'specials' can be much longer than in the example I gave, for example "OFF SP OFF SP OFF SP BC MF". So this code will return these instances as well. Thanks.

Comment: No, not thanks.  Update your question and make it clear what your real requirement is.

Comment: I have updated my question, as per your comment. Sorry about that.